# Display custom error message from iOS broadcasting extension

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

My application bundle consists of the main app (normal iOS application) and broadcasting extension (ReplayKit 2). My app contains a button (`RPSystemBroadcastPickerView`), which opens a system popup to select a broadcasting extension and start it.

The one does not have much control over the state of the broadcasting extension inside the extension, however the extension's class which inherits `RPBroadcastSampleHandler` has one useful method (`finishBroadcastWithError`), which allows us to trigger a fail from the extension (which will in turn end the extension's process and show a popup window, showing an error and 2 buttons).

The `finishBroadcastWithError` method accepts an error as an argument. However there is absolutely [no information in docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpbroadcastsamplehandler/2721526-finishbroadcastwitherror) how to customize the error message shown in this system popup window.

I tried to google in order to understand how to set an error message, because I saw some apps (Mobcrush), which somehow were able to set a custom error message when this popup appears. In order to get more info, I watched both videos about ReplayKit 2 from WWDC 2017 and WWDC 2018, the only slide which mentioned something about error handling in Replay Kit 2 was the one, where the following code was demonstrated:

```swift
let userInfo = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Not Logged In"]
let error = NSError(domain: "RPBroadcastErrorDomain", code: 401, userInfo: userInfo)
finishBroadcastWithError(error)
```

I tried it immediately, but unfortunately it does not have any effect on the error shown in the error popup. I assume that either it's some bug in Replay Kit 2 or that something has been changed and was not documented properly (for some reason Replay Kit 2 is not that well documented and I had to gather pieces of information from different sources to write an app which works).

I even tried setting multiple different keys in a dictionary, hoping that at least one of them will change the error message in a popup window, but none of them worked.

```
func stop(message error: String) {
    let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : error,
                    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey : error,
                    NSLocalizedFailureErrorKey : error]
    let error = NSError(domain: "RPBroadcastErrorDomain", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo)
    finishBroadcastWithError(error)
}
```

Did I miss something in docs? Is there any "official" way to change the error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm getting customized error with this set of parameters:

```swift
let userInfo = [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: "failed to broadcast because...."]
NSError(domain: "ScreenShare", code: -1, userInfo: userInfo)
```

Comment: Where to use the code?